# nodejs - storing client timestamps in a database

Tags: javascript, node.js

Relative newbie to Node.js so please excuse my ignorance.

I just set up a simple TCP server using the tutorial [here](http://nodejs.org/)

In my scenario, a user will connect to the server from a web browser and I am looking for a way to get access to the [TCP Timestamps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#TCP_timestamps) and eventually store them in a database.

It would be really helpful if I can get some pointers as to how I can proceed with this (client side and server side)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to access this low-level information.  It is abstracted by the OS.

The only way to do what you are asking is to implement a packet capture.

https://github.com/mranney/node_pcap

Comment: Thanks, that library looks promising